# Jquery calendar - select date programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my page i have a few buttons

```
button 1 - Monday,
button 2 - Tuesday,
.
.
button 7 - Sunday
```

So when any of the button is clicked, i want that day to be selected in the jquery calendar for the next six months.

For example, if i select the button "Monday", then all Mondays should be selected in the calendar for the next six months.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which calendar do you refer to?

Comment: Multi date picker - jquery

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: Yes..this is the plugin